# Грамотное использование Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Начал изучать Selenium для Python и наткнулся на такую вещь, как webdriver. Имеется такой вопрос: как грамотно использовать webdriver, чтобы программа запустилась на всех компьютерах с разными версиями браузеров? Также видел Remote webdriver, но не могу разобраться, как им воспользоваться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, что бы каждый раз не проверять вручную, какой именно драйвер нужен для каждого пользователя, существует библиотека [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

Ее использование достаточно просто и покрывает большую часть проблем с webdriver.

Примеры использования указаны на той же странице в pypi.org

Comment: Спасибо, благодарен